# Pattern matches bug

Tags: java, android

I have found a bug in Android when calling static method.

> `Pattern.matches(String pattern, String value)`

Here is the bug details:

> let parameter pattern = "`^[a-zA-Z0-9]([\\-a-zA-Z0-9_\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]*)+`";
>
> let value to be a long string containing symbol "@" (in the end will crash almost every time), for example "`Abcjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj@`";
>
> call `Pattern.matches(pattern, value)`;

This method get stuck and do not return anything.

> if input string is short like "`Abc@`", it's fine and return false.
>
> if input a short string like "`Abc@`", then continue to make the string longer like "`Abc@jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj@`, it's fine and return false.

In my application, when I do this in an EditText and click a Button to excute Pattern.mathes (pattern, value).UI will not response and application will crash then.

I found this bug at work when I want to filtering user's input, then I write a simple test case in my own application to recurrent this bug (see btnTestInput () method), here is my application code.

This is mainActivity XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tyouter.timecat.ui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTestInputFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestInput"
        android:text="@string/activity_main_test_input_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is mainActivity.class:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @ViewById
    EditText edtTestInputFilter;

    @ViewById
    Button btnTestInput;

    @Bean
    MainController controller;

    MainAdapter adapter;

    @AfterViews
    void init() {
        TimeCatApplication.BUS.register(this);
    }

    @OptionsItem
    void menuSettings() {

    }

    @OptionsItem
    void menuAbout() {
        controller.onMenuAboutClicked(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MainThread)
    public void onEventMainThread(TestEventBusEvent event) {
        T.showLong(this, getResources().getString(R.string.test_event_success));
    }

    @Override
    protected void initVariables() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void initViews(Bundle savedInstance) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void loadData() {

    }

    @Click
    void btnTestInput() {
        if (InputFilter.projectNameMatches(getTest())) {
            T.showLong(this, "pass");
        }else {
            T.showLong(this, "fail");
        }
    }

    private String getTest() {
        return edtTestInputFilter.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Here is InputFilter.class:

```
public class InputFilter {
    static String mProjectName = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]([\\-a-zA-Z0-9_\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]*)+";

    public static boolean matches(String pattern, String value) {
        return Pattern.matches(pattern, value);
    }

    public static boolean projectNameMatches(String projectName) {
        return matches(mProjectName, projectName);
    }
}
```

My Java version: 1.8.0_51.

My Android build tools and sdk:23.0.1 23.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is a place for getting programming help, not for reporting bugs in frameworks, libraries, or APIs. To report a bug in Android, please go to https://code.google.com/p/android.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report, not a question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me that.It is wired anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is no bug, it is [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). You have nested quantifiers in your pattern. Change it to

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9_\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]*";
```

You do not need the first `^` in the pattern as you use it inside `matches` method that requires the entire string to match the pattern.